# Conversion From XML to PLIST

Tags: c#, iphone, .net, xml, plist

I have a to convert some 1000 xml files from XML to PLIST format(such as `<dict>` and `<arrays>`. Is there already existing tool/application or algorithm available?

Comment: Your tags are C#, iphone and .Net which is confusing. I think you need to specify your situation more with existing examples to get good answer.

Answer (score 2):

What about this one?

http://iappcat.com/plist/bin2xml

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to convert from within C#? If this is not the case, there is a tool called `plutil` available since Mac OS X 10.2:

```
plutil -convert xml1 some_file.plist
```

> plutil can be used to check the syntax of property list files, or convert a plist file from one format to another.

Answer (score 0):

Use an XSLT processor. C# has a nice API to do just that, but if you need to automate it on various platforms, use something portable like: [xsltproc](http://xmlsoft.org/xslt/xsltproc2.html) (which is available virtually everywhere), or [SAXON XSLT](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) (for XSL 2.0, but kind of a nuisance to use).